# How to do custom validation in Semantic UI?

Tags: validation, semantic-ui

In Semantic UI, I already know that you can validate forms, but there are only certain rules you can validate. In my signup form (in my application), I want to check if a user with a certain email already exists in the server. If the email exists, the user cannot signup with that certain email. How would I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried form behaviors "add errors" ? it's in the docs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add custom validation rules to your form.

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.myCustomRule = function(param) {
    // Your validation condition goes here
    return (param <= 10 )? true : false;
}
```

To pass parameters to a rule, use bracket notation in your settings object.

```
 rules: [
         {
           type   : 'myCustomRule[param]',
           prompt : 'Custom Error'
         }
       ]
```

Here is the doc [Adding custom validation rule in semantic](http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#validation-rules)

Comment: Just one addendum: the first argument in 'params' is a field value and the second is the 'param' from type.